# Continuous Deployment Tools with database change control

Tags: tomcat, continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

We have setup our Continuous Integration using SVN and Bamboo.

I need a tool that will take the artifacts (.war) and deploy them to a number of environments.

The following are requirements:

1. Tomcat Support
2. Windows Server 2008
3. Database change control support
4. Configuration support.

The deploy needs to deploy the application and database and configuration changes to numerous different client instances (with different databases).

I have set this up with LiveRebel, but I believe the pricing structure will prevent us from doing what is required (ie a lot of client servers = a lot of agents).

Does anyone else have a similar setup and use another tool ?

Answer (score 0):

Before looking into other tools you can check first the existing bamboo plugins and deployments plans.

You can use the "deploy Tomcat application" task from deployment plans for the installation of war files, restarting application, etc

The script task can be used for adding a .bat or .ps scripting in relation to the database changes.

If you decide to go for an external tool you can look into rundeck for some automation: http://rundeck.org/

**Bamboo deployments plan documentation:** https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Deployment+projects#Deploymentprojects-Howdodeploymentprojectswork?